# SplitScreen in Iphone/Ipod Touch

Tags: iphone, split, screen, ipod-touch

Just wonder anyone has idea how to create a view controller class doing splitscreen, like UISplitViewController, but can use in IPhone/IPod Touch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the `UISplitViewController` [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Split view controllers are for use
>   exclusively on iPad devices.
>   Attempting to create one on other
>   devices results in an exception.

Comment: I know, joust wonder any developer has custom view controller doing similar job as UISplitViewController but work in IPhone/IPod

Comment: @interman: You may want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260762/coding-custom-splitviewcontroller-when-should-i-call-viewwillappear-viewdidapp) for ideas.